# react-big-calendar customise time slots

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I'm looking for a way to customise the time slots area on the left of the week and day view.
Is there any way to customise labels ?
[image: Big calendar]

I mean if I choose for instance as props :

- step={15}
- timeslots={2}

The labels appear only every other time and not on each slot. I would like to add the missing label with another font style.

I did not find anything about in the API documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internal `TimeGutter` only applies the `formats.timeGutterFormat` once per slot group, and I don't think that component can be overridden. You can target it for style changes though.

```css
.rbc-time-gutter > .rbc-timeslot-group > .rbc-time-slot > .rbc-label {
 text-align: right;
 font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Steve -Cutter- Blades